# Error Consuming a SOAP Web Service

Tags: web-services

I am trying to consume a web service that is exposed by [Percussion CMS][1] in order to create content items programmatically. When attempting to add the web reference in Visual Studio 2008, however, Visual Studio alerts with me the following:

> The document was understood, but it
>   could not be processed:
>
> - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
> - DTD is prohibited in this XML document.

I have no experience working with Percussion CMS, so I haven't a clue where to start to resolve this problem. Is there some Visual Studio setting that I might be able to override to make this work?

I've already requested assistance from the Percussion tech support, but that was Monday and I haven't gotten any useful/helpful information back.

**Edit**: Just in case this helps resolve the issue, below is the entire WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="content" targetNamespace="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/content" xmlns:com="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/common" xmlns:con="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/content" xmlns:flt="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/faults" xmlns:ns="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/systemServices" xmlns:ns1="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/uiServices" xmlns:ns2="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/assemblyServices" xmlns:ns3="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/securityServices" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

&lt;wsdl:types&gt;

    &lt;xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;

        &lt;xsd:import namespace="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/faults" schemaLocation="../faults.xsd"&gt;

        &lt;/xsd:import&gt;

    &lt;/xsd:schema&gt;

    &lt;xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:www.percussion.com/6.0.0/content" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;

        &lt;xsd:include schemaLocation="content.xsd"/&gt;

    &lt;/xsd:schema&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:types&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AuthenticationHeader"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="com:PSAuthenticationHeader" name="Session"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="empty"/&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadKeywordsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadKeywordsRequest" name="LoadKeywordsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadKeywordsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadKeywordsResponse" name="LoadKeywordsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadLocalesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadLocalesRequest" name="LoadLocalesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadLocalesResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadLocalesResponse" name="LoadLocalesResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadTranslationSettingsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadTranslationSettingsResponse" name="LoadTranslationSettingsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadContentTypesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadContentTypesRequest" name="LoadContentTypesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadContentTypesResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadContentTypesResponse" name="LoadContentTypesResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CreateItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CreateItemsRequest" name="CreateItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CreateItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CreateItemsResponse" name="CreateItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindItemsRequest" name="FindItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindItemsResponse" name="FindItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadItemsRequest" name="LoadItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadItemsResponse" name="LoadItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveItemsRequest" name="SaveItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveItemsResponse" name="SaveItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="DeleteItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:DeleteItemsRequest" name="DeleteItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ViewItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:ViewItemsRequest" name="ViewItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ViewItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:ViewItemsResponse" name="ViewItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="PrepareForEditRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:PrepareForEditRequest" name="PrepareForEditRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="PrepareForEditResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:PrepareForEditResponse" name="PrepareForEditResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ReleaseFromEditRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:ReleaseFromEditRequest" name="ReleaseFromEditRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewCopiesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewCopiesRequest" name="NewCopiesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewCopiesResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewCopiesResponse" name="NewCopiesResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewPromotableVersionsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewPromotableVersionsRequest" name="NewPromotableVersionsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewPromotableVersionsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewPromotableVersionsResponse" name="NewPromotableVersionsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewTranslationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewTranslationsRequest" name="NewTranslationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NewTranslationsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:NewTranslationsResponse" name="NewTranslationsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindRevisionsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindRevisionsRequest" name="FindRevisionsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindRevisionsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindRevisionsResponse" name="FindRevisionsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="PromoteRevisionsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:PromoteRevisionsRequest" name="PromoteRevisionsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CheckinItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CheckinItemsRequest" name="CheckinItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CheckoutItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CheckoutItemsRequest" name="CheckoutItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="GetAssemblyUrlsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:GetAssemblyUrlsRequest" name="GetAssemblyUrlsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="GetAssemblyUrlsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:GetAssemblyUrlsResponse" name="GetAssemblyUrlsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CreateChildEntriesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CreateChildEntriesRequest" name="CreateChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="CreateChildEntriesResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:CreateChildEntriesResponse" name="CreateChildEntriesResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadChildEntriesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadChildEntriesRequest" name="LoadChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadChildEntriesResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadChildEntriesResponse" name="LoadChildEntriesResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveChildEntriesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveChildEntriesRequest" name="SaveChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="DeleteChildEntriesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:DeleteChildEntriesRequest" name="DeleteChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ReorderChildEntriesRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:ReorderChildEntriesRequest" name="ReorderChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddContentRelationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddContentRelationsRequest" name="AddContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddContentRelationsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddContentRelationsResponse" name="AddContentRelationsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadContentRelationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadContentRelationsRequest" name="LoadContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadContentRelationsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadContentRelationsResponse" name="LoadContentRelationsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveContentRelationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveContentRelationsRequest" name="SaveContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="DeleteContentRelationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:DeleteContentRelationsRequest" name="DeleteContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ReorderContentRelationsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:ReorderContentRelationsRequest" name="ReorderContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindChildItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindChildItemsRequest" name="FindChildItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindChildItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindChildItemsResponse" name="FindChildItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindParentItemsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindParentItemsRequest" name="FindParentItemsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindParentItemsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindParentItemsResponse" name="FindParentItemsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadFoldersRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadFoldersRequest" name="LoadFoldersRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="LoadFoldersResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:LoadFoldersResponse" name="LoadFoldersResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveFoldersRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveFoldersRequest" name="SaveFoldersRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="SaveFoldersResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:SaveFoldersResponse" name="SaveFoldersResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="DeleteFoldersRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:DeleteFoldersRequest" name="DeleteFoldersRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddFolderRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddFolderRequest" name="AddFolderRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddFolderResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddFolderResponse" name="AddFolderResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddFolderTreeRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddFolderTreeRequest" name="AddFolderTreeRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddFolderTreeResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddFolderTreeResponse" name="AddFolderTreeResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindFolderChildrenRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindFolderChildrenRequest" name="FindFolderChildrenRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindFolderChildrenResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindFolderChildrenResponse" name="FindFolderChildrenResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="AddFolderChildrenRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:AddFolderChildrenRequest" name="AddFolderChildrenRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="RemoveFolderChildrenRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:RemoveFolderChildrenRequest" name="RemoveFolderChildrenRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="MoveFolderChildrenRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:MoveFolderChildrenRequest" name="MoveFolderChildrenRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindFolderPathRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindFolderPathRequest" name="FindFolderPathRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindFolderPathResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindFolderPathResponse" name="FindFolderPathResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindPathIdsRequest"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindPathIdsRequest" name="FindPathIdsRequest"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="FindPathIdsResponse"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="con:FindPathIdsResponse" name="FindPathIdsResponse"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ContractViolationFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSContractViolationFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="InvalidSessionFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSInvalidSessionFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="NotAuthorizedFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSNotAuthorizedFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="UnknownContentTypeFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSUnknownContentTypeFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="UnknownChildFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSUnknownChildFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ErrorResultsFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSErrorResultsFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:message name="ErrorsFaultMessage"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:part element="flt:PSErrorsFault" name="fault"/&gt;

&lt;/wsdl:message&gt;

&lt;wsdl:portType name="content"&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadKeywords"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:LoadKeywordsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadKeywordsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadLocales"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:LoadLocalesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadLocalesResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadTranslationSettings"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadTranslationSettingsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadContentTypes"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:LoadContentTypesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadContentTypesResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="CreateItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:CreateItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:CreateItemsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownContentTypeFaultMessage" name="UnknownContentTypeFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="FindItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:FindItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:FindItemsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:LoadItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadItemsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="SaveItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:SaveItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:SaveItemsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="DeleteItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:DeleteItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="ViewItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:ViewItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:ViewItemsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="PrepareForEdit"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:PrepareForEditRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:PrepareForEditResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="ReleaseFromEdit"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:ReleaseFromEditRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="NewCopies"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:NewCopiesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:NewCopiesResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="NewPromotableVersions"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:NewPromotableVersionsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:NewPromotableVersionsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="NewTranslations"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:NewTranslationsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:NewTranslationsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="FindRevisions"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:FindRevisionsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:FindRevisionsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="PromoteRevisions"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:PromoteRevisionsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="CheckinItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:CheckinItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="CheckoutItems"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:CheckoutItemsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="GetAssemblyUrls"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:GetAssemblyUrlsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:GetAssemblyUrlsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="CreateChildEntries"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:CreateChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:CreateChildEntriesResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownChildFaultMessage" name="UnknownChildFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="LoadChildEntries"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:LoadChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:LoadChildEntriesResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownChildFaultMessage" name="UnknownChildFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorResultsFaultMessage" name="ErrorResultsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="SaveChildEntries"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:SaveChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownChildFaultMessage" name="UnknownChildFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="DeleteChildEntries"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:DeleteChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownChildFaultMessage" name="UnknownChildFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="ReorderChildEntries"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:ReorderChildEntriesRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:empty"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:UnknownChildFaultMessage" name="UnknownChildFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ErrorsFaultMessage" name="ErrorsFault"/&gt;

    &lt;/wsdl:operation&gt;

    &lt;wsdl:operation name="AddContentRelations"&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:input message="con:AddContentRelationsRequest"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:output message="con:AddContentRelationsResponse"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:ContractViolationFaultMessage" name="ContractViolationFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:InvalidSessionFaultMessage" name="InvalidSessionFault"/&gt;

        &lt;wsdl:fault message="con:NotAuthorizedFaultMessage" name="NotAuthorizedFault"/&gt;

Answer (score 0):

This is way too late to help you, but maybe not for the next guy....

My understanding is that .NET and J2EE webservices use slightly different dialects of WSDL.  Visual Studio doesn't understand the other one.  (The great thing about standards is that there are so many of them to choose from....)

As of v6.7 (and probably earlier), there are two sample applications for communicating with Percussion via the web services, one for Java, one for C#.  The C# version can be found in:

\WebServices\6.0.0\sample\loader\csharp

Under that directory, you will find "Web References" and below that "RxWebServices."

The RxWebServices directory contains WSDL which allows your .NET code to work with Percussion.